# Spring Boot MessageSource Cannot find code

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Data Rest, and Spring MVC. I've defined a `messages_en_US.properties` file in my `src/main/resources` directory with my codes and messages.

I'm using Spring Data Rest and the Spring Validator implementation with both annotation-based validation on my Entities, as well as custom validations using the Spring Data Rest Validator logic described in the docs.

The problem is that I can never get the application to return the messages from the `messages_en_US.properties` file. It always says that the code is not found.

One issue is that the Spring Boot MessageSourceAutoConfiguration is never coniguring the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` because an earlier bean was configuring the `DelegatingMessageSource` instance. But even when I configure my own `Bean` that defines a `ResourceBundleMessageSource`, none of the messages can be found. I always get a stack trace from AbstractMessageSource that it cannot find the code.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. Does anyone have any insight into how to debug or troubleshoot why its not finding the message. Or the answer?!

Comment: May be you share your code for more clarity.

Comment: I don't really have any code to share. I'm pretty much using standard Spring Boot (1.2.x) and attribute validations (@Pattern, @Email) on my entity class. The only custom code is the cut-and-paste of the code to create the ```ResourceBundleMessageSource``` from ```MessageSourceAutoConfiguration```.